# Using pear : Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 6144 bytes)

Tags: php, email, pear

when i am trying to send a mail using PEAR, I got the following error:

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 6144 bytes)

I am searched in this site, and found some solutions like
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

But I am getting the same error. Please help me...

```
<?php
    include('Mail.php');

    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    $headers = array("From"=>"mymail@gmail.com", "Subject"=>"Test Mail");
    $body = "This is a test!";
    $mail = Mail::factory("mail");
    $mail->send("friend@example.com", $headers, $body);
?>
```

### Update

Actually I used the code : 
 ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
Because, when I looked into php.ini file, I found it was set as 128M. So i changed the value to 256M there and also in the code. But it didn't work. So i tried with 512M, and then finally with -1.

Thank you...

Comment: You are exceeding the 128 MB limit that is set by default for PHP. Is this all the code in the script that is causing the error? It seems very unlikely that just this is enough to exceed the memory_limit.

Comment: Which row causes the problem? Is it `$mail->send()`?

Comment: @datasage is right. Instead of finding ways to increase memory limit, find out why this 6 line code is eating up so much memory.

Answer (score 2):

First, try setting `memory_limit` to 128M or something. Sending mail should not take that much memory, so if that doesn't work, there's probably something wrong in the Mail-class you're using. Are you sure you're using the latest version?

Besides that, what you're trying to accomplish can be easily done using native PHP:

```
mail("friend@example.com", "Subject", $body, implode($headers, "\r\n"));
```

Comment: (1) `memory_limit` is already set to `128M` (or 134217728 bytes, mentioned in error message). (2) I believe he needs something more than sending message with `$body` set to "This is a test!". While `mail()` would be sufficient for such basic messages, I would not use it for sending more complex messages (with both `text/plain` and `text/html` bodies and with attachments). I also would not try to send complex messages until I am able to send basic test message (like the one in a question).